# Why is this function still running on desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this accordion in my footer that should only run on mobile.
When I have it run on desktop initially the function doesn't run, which is what I want. But if I switch to mobile view and then back to desktop, the function is still working... I'm still able to click the h5 and show/hide the text below... this shouldn't be happening on desktop though, I don't understand the issue..

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/WNZqEge) so you can see the resize issue.

```js
// On resize run the check screen size function
$(window).on("resize", function (e) {
    checkScreenSize();
});
// Run the check screen size function on load
checkScreenSize();

// check screen size function
function checkScreenSize(){
    var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();

    // Run the accordion function on screens less than 1024
    if (newWindowWidth < 1024) {
        footerAccordion();
    } 
}

// Accordion function
function footerAccordion() {
    $('.footer__locations p').hide();
    $(".footer__locations").find("h5").click(function() {
        $(".footer__locations").find("h5").removeClass('active');
        $('.footer__locations p').slideUp();
        var selected = $(this).next('.footer__locations p');
        if (selected.is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next('.footer__locations p').slideDown();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="row footer__locations-row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 footer__locations">
                        <h5>TITLE TWO</h5>
                        <p>THIS IS SOME TEXT TWO</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 footer__locations">
                        <h5>TITLE TWO</h5>
                        <p>THIS IS SOME TEXT TWO</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: What makes you think it would stop once you've added a click listener at least once?

Comment: I thought that because the check screen size function runs whenever the window resizes that it would only run the function were true, If false nothing should happen? But if it's already been true previously then the function still exists....?

Comment: You never remove the countless click listeners your code adds every time `footerAccordion` runs. An event listener that has been added and never gets removed of course stays active until you remove it, or remove the elements you've bound the listener to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a reverse accordion function and

```
function reverseFooterAccordion() {
    $('.footer__locations p').show();
    $(".footer__locations").find("h5").off("click.namespace") // use namespaces to on and off click handler
}
```

call it on else condition

```
if (newWindowWidth < 1024) {
    footerAccordion();
} else reverseFooterAccordion()
```

Proper implemented footerAccordion will look like

```
function footerAccordion() {
    $('.footer__locations p').hide();
    $(".footer__locations").find("h5").off("click.namespace").on("click.namespace",function() {
        $(".footer__locations").find("h5").removeClass('active');
        $('.footer__locations p').slideUp();
        var selected = $(this).next('.footer__locations p');
        if (selected.is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next('.footer__locations p').slideDown();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

PS: Add debounce on resize listener for performance

Comment: While this is a very jQuery style solution that will work, it lacks an explanation of why OP's problem occurred, and another explanation as of what your code does to remedy that.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're assigning the Click action and never removing it. One work-around is just to embrace that - put your mobile check in the click handler. Then use CSS to handle the hiding/showing of the p element.

```
function IsMobileScreenSize(){
    var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();

    // true if screens less than 1024
    if (newWindowWidth < 1024) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//      $('.footer__locations p').hide(); // Handle UI in CSS instead

// Accordion function just set it always
$(".footer__locations").find("h5").click(function() {
    // Only do for larger screen sizes, otherwise just stop here
    if ( ! IsMobileScreenSize() )
        return;
    $(".footer__locations").find("h5").removeClass('active');
    $('.footer__locations p').slideUp();
    var selected = $(this).next('.footer__locations p');
    if (selected.is(":hidden")) {
    $(this).next('.footer__locations p').slideDown();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

Finally, your checkScreenSize function will look like below

```
function checkScreenSize(){
    if (IsMobileScreenSize()) {
      $('.footer__locations p').hide();
    } else {
      $('.footer__locations p').show();      
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the final missing bit to your answer. Please edit it if that is not what you suggested